# What does <* in Haskell readP do?

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming, monads

I have encountered `<*` in the Haskell `readP` library on several occassions, I am however not yet sure what it does, and couldn't find it in the library documentation. Is it the same as `<++` ?

Comment: What do you mean you didn't find it? [Hoogle has it](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%3C*&scope=set%3Astackage)!

Comment: Ah, thank you. That is because I try to find it using google, and I assumed it was a `readP` library function, it seems to be just a monadic operator.

Comment: @cafce25 based on the  Hoogle descriptions I am still unsure of its function exactly. And how it is different from `<*>` , I see the type definitions on Hoogle and some sparse descriptions such as _Sequence actions, discarding the value of the second argument_. But what is then meant by this, that the second monad is ignored in `f a -> f b -> f a`? And will side-effects then be presereved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**`(<*) :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--42-) is not specific to `ReadP`, it is part or `Applicative`, and essentially boils down to:

```
f <* g = do
  y <- f
  g
  pure y
```

but this is, unless using an `ApplicativeDo` for monads. But it makes it quite clear what is happening.

Behind the curtains it is implemented as:

```
f <* g = liftA2 const f g
```

so it "merges" two `Applicative f => f a`s, and by using `const`, it will take the first item, not the second.

it thus uses the left operand, then the right, and return the result of the first one.

In the context of the `ReadP`, it thus will run the left parser, then the right, and then omit the result of the right parser and return the first parser.

For example:

```
get <* get
```

it will read *two* characters, and return the first parsed character, so ignoring (but parsing) the right character.

The [**`(<++) :: ReadP a -> ReadP a -> ReadP`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html#v:-60--43--43-) is about *choices* where you present two choices as parser, and you first try to run the left parser, and if that fails the second parser. But here if for example the first parser matches, it will never run the second parser for the rest of the stream.